# Отключить firebase в тестовых сборках android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-android

Как отключить firebase в тестовых сборках во android разработке? 
Как сделать чтобы определенный код был только в тестовых сборках?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
     //Код
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Это все можно сделать с помощью Product Flavors. Создать два productFlavors: один тестовый, один любой другой. Вот [пример](http://azagroup.ru/gradle-buildtypes-and-productflavors-android/)

Comment: чтобы подключить firebase достаточно добавить соответствующую зависимость в gradle. Могу ли я сделать так, чтобы некоторые библиотеки firebase(например библиотека крэшей) собирались только в релизной версии?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24910671/7104538 вот пример как подключать разные либы для разных productFlavors